# Micromax MMX 355g USB 3G Dongle

Tags: networking, internet, modem

I am new to ubuntu . I'm using ubuntu 14.04. Please help me I am unable to connect to the internet using my Micromax mmx 355g 3g modem.
In windows it was very easy as modem was auto detected by it. But here I'm getting problem. Please tell me step by step procedure to connect to internet...
Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: what is the output of `lsusb` and `lspci` after connecting your dongle? Paste them in your question

Answer (score 0):

up vote
0
down vote
accepted
The vendor id of the modem is OMEGA TECHNOLOGY. For connecting to the internet with the modem,

1. At first click on the networking icon on the top right side of the screen
2. Then click on the edit connection button
3. Then click on the add connection and chose mobile broadband from the drop down list.
4. Then chose usb modem configuration option and hit continue
5. select your country and continue
6. select your provider and then on the next page select plan if you have a 3g plan then select web or for 2g select gprs
7. Then apply settings. Okay! you have configured your modem.

Now you have to connect to the internet for that click on the networking button again and enable networking if not enabled then you'll see your new connection named with the service provider's name is there . Now just click on that and see if it works. It worked for me. I have a micromax 310g bsnl3g(unlocked)modem using aircel. Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I have given the step by step procedure from scratch as asked,

1. Search for Network Connections in the Unity Dash. Click on the add button -> Choose Mobile Broadband option from drop-down menu -> Then choose the appropriate options.When asked to select a plan, choose the 'Default' option if you are not sure which plan you are using.
2. Now click on the network icon situated at the top right side, and click on the newly created connection. If it works, well and good, but if it fails, follow the below steps.
3. After this, search for Network Connections in the unity dash and edit your newly created connection and go to the PPP settings tab.[image]
4. Click configure methods, try disabling some of the authentication methods, and try connection to internet again. I have only PAP and MSCHAP v2 enabled and it is works fine for me.[image]

Hope it helped!